# Growing a vector in a iterator based loop crashes in destructing with munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer, why?

Tags: c++

Could someone explain the reason why my program crashes when I use an iterator based for loop and not when I'm using an index-based for loop? I suspect it is because the index based `for()` is evaluated every time and the iterator based `for()` statement somehow is not.

I'm trying to loop over a vector, and when the last element is reached and it is one I'm looking for, resize the vector and add one more element. There is no difference in crashing if I use `push_back` or `resize`.

This is toy code, as an example an learning experience. I want to know why one crashes and the other does not.

The following code crashes when the destructor of the vector is called with an error `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> exampleVector {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    // iterator based loop
    for (auto it = exampleVector.begin(); it != exampleVector.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it == 5 && std::next(it) == exampleVector.end()) {
            exampleVector.resize(exampleVector.size() + 1);
            *std::next(it) = 999;
            *it = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Stack copied from clion debug window:

```
__GI_raise 0x00007f8cd892ce97
__GI_abort 0x00007f8cd892e801
__libc_message 0x00007f8cd8977897
malloc_printerr 0x00007f8cd897e90a
munmap_chunk 0x00007f8cd8985ecc
__GI___libc_free 0x00007f8cd8985ecc
__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate new_allocator.h:125
std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::deallocate alloc_traits.h:462
std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate stl_vector.h:180
std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::~_Vector_base stl_vector.h:162
std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector stl_vector.h:435
main main.cpp:5
__libc_start_main 0x00007f8cd890fb97
_start 0x000055f736f6aaca
```

This program does not:

```
#includee <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> exampleVector {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    // indexed for loop
    for (size_t i = 0; i < exampleVector.size(); ++i) {
        if (exampleVector.at(i) == 5 and exampleVector.at(i) == exampleVector.back()) {
            exampleVector.resize(exampleVector.size() + 1);
            exampleVector.at(i + 1) = 999;
            exampleVector.at(i) = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On Ubuntu 18.04, default versions of gcc you get when doing `apt install build-essential`.

Again, looking for the reason why one crashes and not the other. Also, does this apply to a range based for loop?

Comment: In your second example, you don't need to use `at()`, use `operator[]` instead, since you know `i` is always within bounds of `exampleVector`. `at()` performs bounds checking, `operator[]` does not. Don't forcibly invoke overhead you don't actually need.

Comment: Also, `std::next(it) == exampleVector.end()` and `exampleVector.at(i) == exampleVector.back()` are not equivalent comparisons.  The first checks if the current element is the last element in the vector. The second checks if the *value* of the current element is equal to the *value* of the last element. Not the same comparison. In the second case, you would need to use `(i+1) == exampleVector.size()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you resize a `std::vector`, iterators that are pointing into it might get invalidated. So you need to reset `it` after resizing:

```
if (*it == 5 && std::next(it) == exampleVector.end()) {
     exampleVector.resize(exampleVector.size() + 1);
     it = std::next(exampleVector.begin(), exampleVector.size() - 2);
     // ...
}
```

Obviously, indexes are just `int`s, so there is no issue about them becoming invalid, so your second example works fine.

Range-for loops are just pretty syntax for an iterator based loop, so yes, it would have the same issue as the first version.

Comment: Given the example provided by the OP, you would need something more like this instead: `auto index = std::distance(exampleVector.begin(), it); exampleVector.resize(exampleVector.size() + 1); it = std::next(exampleVector.begin(), index);`

Comment: I like your approach better, however you would need to use `-2` instead of `-1` so that `it` continues to refer to the same element it did before the `resize()`, so that the loop can then `++it` afterwards to advance to the next element correctly. Otherwise you would have to skip the `++it` on the iteration that `resize()`'s

Comment: Good catch. There was also another issue, advance is a void function :p fixed that too.

Comment: `std::next()` has an optional `n` parameter, as I showed in my earlier comment: `it = std::next(exampleVector.begin(), exampleVector.size() - 2);`

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Could you please explain why the for loop condition, `for (size_t i = 0; i < exampleVector.size(); ++i)`, does pick up the new size each time the loop runs and     `for (auto it = exampleVector.begin(); it != exampleVector.end(); ++it)` does not? The assignment, `auto it =`, should, sort of, reset the it value every time the loop runs just as the `size()` one?